# Pandas Dataframe - How to get a multiline cell separated by carriage return into multiple rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

thank you for taking time to look into this. I'm a beginner programmer and struck at this.

```
#the dataframe is as follows for reference
data = [['\r8', 'tom', 10, '55\r \r \r62\r75'], ['18\r\r9', 'nick', 15, '77\r25\r85'], ['17\r19\r18', 'juli', 14, '55\r75\r85']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Roll No per Class', 'Name', 'Age', 'Highest Scores'])
```

This is a sample dataframe, the original one spans over more than 15,000 rows and 10 columns.

I want the /r cells to be placed into a new row with the other columns repeating.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwCVx.png)

I have tried the code mentioned below

```
import numpy as np from itertools import chain

# return list from series of comma-separated strings def chainer(s):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(s.str.split('\r')))

# calculate lengths of splits lens = df['Highest Scores'].str.split(',').map(len)

# create new dataframe, repeating or chaining as appropriate res = pd.DataFrame({'Name': np.repeat(df['Name'], lens),
                    'Age': np.repeat(df['Age'], lens),
                    'Roll No per Class': chainer(df['Roll No per Class']),
                    'Highest Scores': chainer(df['Highest Scores'])})
```

I'm getting the error:
`ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length`

I have also tried the code -

```
df.set_index(['Name', 'Age']).apply(lambda x: x.str.split('\r').explode()).reset_index()
```

It also gives an error :

```
ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

I'm guessing this is because the length of Roll number column doesn't match the length of Highest Scores column.

Can someone please help look into this. This is my first post so do let me know if there is anything missing and needs to be added.

Comment: `df.set_index(['Name', 'Age']).apply(lambda x: x.str.split('\r').explode()).reset_index()`

Comment: Please don't post images of code, post the actual code instead.

Comment: @tdy already tried this as mentioned in thread I have linked. It shows - "ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!"

Comment: 1. The purpose of a [mre] is so we can test if our solutions are valid. Both my code and fsimonjetz's code work with your sample `df`, so that sample isn't useful. A sample `df` should _reproduce_ your issues.

Comment: 2. You should post the exact code you've tried. Your screenshot only shows that you tried the `itertools` method. Don't just link to a post and say "I tried these" as a blanket statement. Sometimes people copy/apply code in the wrong way, etc.

Comment: @tdy Apologies for that and thank you for your insights. I'm actually working with a confidential dataset and tried to make a sample on my own but given the vastness, I wasn't able to provide a more accurate condition. I have edited my question and I'm confident that this time it certainly is accurate. Could you be so kind to look at it once now?

Comment: @Beginner_profile I see -- with the updated `df`, as you mentioned the rolls and scores are sometimes mismatched. You first have to decide how you want to match up the mismatched elements. For example, splitting `tom`'s row would give `roll=['' ,'8']` and `scores=['55', ' ', ' ', '62', '75']`. Which score should roll 8 be mapped with?

Comment: @tdy The order doesn't matter here. What matters is both that roll and scores should be against Tom's name and Age.

Comment: IMO it doesn't make sense to keep the exploded lists in one frame if there's no correspondence between row values. I would explode them separately: first `rolls = df.set_index(['Name', 'Age'])['Roll No per Class'].str.split().explode().to_frame()` and then `scores = df.set_index(['Name', 'Age'])['Highest Scores'].str.split().explode().to_frame()`

Comment: Then if you really wanted to combine them, I would merge on `name`/`age` so that every row has meaning: `rolls.join(scores)`

Comment: @tdy that actually gave repetitive enteries which would not be the optimal solution, although it might work.

Comment: @tdy but your answer gave me an idea, I looped through each row first, making the lists equal (which needs to be exploded) and then used explode. Voila, it worked! I have been on this problem for a whole day now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can split the cells at `\r` first,

```py
>>> cols = ['Roll No per Class', 'Highest Scores']
>>> df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda col: col.str.split("\r"))
>>> df
  Roll No per Class  Name  Age Highest Scores
0           [, , 8]   tom   10   [55, 62, 75]
1         [18, , 9]  nick   15   [77, 25, 85]
2      [17, 19, 18]  juli   14   [55, 75, 85]
```

and `explode` them after:

```py
>>> df.explode(cols)
  Roll No per Class  Name  Age Highest Scores
0                     tom   10             55
0                     tom   10             62
0                 8   tom   10             75
1                18  nick   15             77
1                    nick   15             25
1                 9  nick   15             85
2                17  juli   14             55
2                19  juli   14             75
2                18  juli   14             85
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but it is showing the error - "ValueError: columns must have matching element counts"